# How to translate mysql query to sequelize orm

Tags: javascript, mysql, left-join, sequelize.js

I need to perform this multiple LEFT JOIN query with sequelize:

```
SELECT movie, genre FROM `yt_movies` M 
LEFT JOIN `genres_link` GL ON M.id = GL.movie_id
LEFT JOIN `genres` G ON GL.genre_id = G.id
WHERE M.id = 1098
```

I tried

```
const YtMovies = db.yt_movies;
const Genres = db.genres;
const GenresLink = db.genres_link;

YtMovies.hasMany(GenresLink, { as: 'GL', foreignKey: 'movie_id' });
YtMovies.hasMany(Genres, { as: 'G', foreignKey: 'genre' });

const res = await db.yt_movies.findAll({
                    attributes: ['movie'],
                    where: { id: movie_id },
                    include: [
                        {
                            model: db.genres_link,
                            as: 'GL',
                            required: false,
                            attributes: ['genre_id'],
                        },
                        {
                            model: db.genres,
                            required: false,
                            as: 'G',
                            attributes: ['genre'],
                        },
                    ],
                });
```

the returned query looks like

```
SELECT
`yt_movies`.`id`,
`yt_movies`.`movie`,
`GL`.`id` AS `GL.id`,
`GL`.`genre_id` AS `GL.genre_id`,
`G`.`id` AS `G.id`,
`G`.`genre` AS `G.genre`
FROM `yt_movies` AS `yt_movies`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres_link` AS `GL` ON `yt_movies`.`id` = `GL`.`movie_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres` AS `G` ON `yt_movies`.`id` = `G`.`genre`
WHERE `yt_movies`.`id` = 1098;
```

in the last two string we can see that it uses ON with `yt_movies`
but i expect it to use ON with `genres_link`

```
LEFT JOIN `genres` AS G ON GL.genre_id = G.id <-- expected
```

I guess i don't really understand table associations and messed up with hasMany or I miss another statement

tables look like

**yt_movies**

```
| id | movie   | pj | pq|
|----|---------|----|---|
|  1 |Avatar   |    |   |
|  2 |Predator |    |   |
|  3 |...      |    |   |
```

**genres_link**

```
| id | genre_id| movie_id |
|----|---------|----------|
|  1 |  12     |    1     | // avatar
|  2 |  13     |    2     | // predator
|  3 |  14     |    2     | // predator
```

**genres**

```
| id | genre    |
|----|----------|
| 12 | action   | 
| 13 | thriller | 
| 14 | horror   |
```

all I did is managed to perform first LEFT JOIN... adding second include didn't help, and Im afraid I don't truely undestand table associations even after reading the docs :|

I guess i need to use belongsToMany, but at the moment i don't understand how :))

I appreciate all the help!
Thanks and HALP!

Comment: Can you please share the relation definitions?

Comment: @RohitDalal Hey, i attached some table examples
I guess i need to use belongsToMany, but at the moment i don't understand how :))

Comment: Shouldn't it be - LEFT OUTER JOIN `genres` AS `G` ON `GL `.`genre_id ` = `G`.`genre_id `
Your sql of sequelize is not correct. yt_movies is not linked with genres table. genres_link is linked with genre table

Comment: Please share the models code. Can share via - https://pastebin.com

Comment: @RohitDalal
> Shouldn't it be - LEFT OUTER JOIN genres AS G ON GL .genre_id = G.genre_id Your sql of sequelize is not correct

Thats what i am talking about.
here is a bin - https://pastebin.com/dLdusCft

Comment: Please share the relations code where you defined the relations

Comment: @RohitDalal
`const YtMovies = db.yt_movies;
const Genres = db.genres;
const GenresLink = db.genres_link;
YtMovies.hasMany(GenresLink, { as: 'GL', foreignKey: 'movie_id' });
YtMovies.hasMany(Genres, { as: 'G', foreignKey: 'genre' });`
these are only relations I defined;

i have also updated the bin https://pastebin.com/dLdusCft

Comment: the relations are wrong YtMovies do no has Many genere directly. As its a n:m relation you have to use through option in relation. As pointed out by @KenOn10 below. There is a third table involved genres_link between the relation of yt_movies and genres tables.

Comment: @RohitDalal thanks for help! i did ``YtMovies.belongsToMany(Genres, { through: GenresLink, foreignKey: 'movie_id' });
Genres.belongsToMany(YtMovies, { through: GenresLink, foreignKey: 'genre_id' });`` but it didn't help - error genres_link is not associated to yt_movies!

Answer (score 0):

To join A->B->C, you should nest the include for C inside the include for B, e.g.

```
A.findAll({    
    include: [
       {
         model: B,
         include: [
             {model: C}
             ]
         }
     ]
     })
```

But, if table genres_link has no attributes other than PKs of movie and genre, then use **through**.

```
   YtMovies.belongsToMany(Genres, {through: GenresLink, foreignKey: 'movie_id' });
   Genres.belongsToMany (YtMovies,{through: GenresLink, foreignKey: 'genre_id '});

    YtMovies.findAll({    
       include: [
          {
           model: Genres, 
           required : true,
           through: GenresLink 
          }
          ]
       });
```

The [manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html#n-m) has some helpful info on this topic...