# How to write an Inner Join query using sequelize ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, join, orm, sequelize.js

My inner join query looks as below

```
SELECT list.id, list.name,
sa.createdBy
FROM list 
INNER JOIN data sa 
               ON sa.listId = list.id 
WHERE sa.type = 'type1'
and sa.data = 'data1'
```

I am trying to write the above query using sequelize ORM.
I have written the following query but it is not giving desired result.

```
list.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: data,
    required: true
    where: {type: 'type1'}
   }]
}).then(list => {
  /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Have a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/55354324/10910692 . Although there's only one un-accepted answer but I think there's a reference on how to do the join. It seems like you just need to put the second tables in `{}` similarly as the first table and separate them by comma.

Answer (score 0):

Your where clause doesn't fully contain the query you wrote

```
list.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: data,
    required: true,
    where: {
       type: 'type1', // sa.type = 'type1'
       data: 'data1', // sa.data = 'data1'
    },
   }]
}).then(lists => { // renamed to lists to prevent shadowing the "list" model variable
  /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Where do i need to include `ON sa.listId = list.id`?  Also, how to fetch `sa.createdBy`

Comment: If your `data` table is correctly associated to the `list` table in your model definitions, then the "include" does the `ON` part for you. I don't know if you have a one-to-one or a one-to-many relationship between list and data, but you can paste your model code if you want me to look.
Right now, your query is bringing back all attributes of both tables, so the `createdBy` should be there if it's a column in the `data` table. It depends on how your models are: one to one or one to many. I'll show you for each.

Comment: ```then(lists => {
  if (lists.length) { 
    const first = lists[0];
    const firstCreatedByOneToOne = first.data.createdBy; // one-to-one
    const firstCreatedByOneToMany = first.data[0].createdBy; // one-to-many, gets createdBy of first joined record
  }
});
```